# Set default value for combo box in MS Access form

Tags: ms-access, combobox, default-value

I have a combo box called dropBoolType2. I tried setting the Default Value under the Data property tab to

```
=[dropBoolType2].[ListIndex](1)]
```

but I'm still getting a blank default value.

Comment: What is the bound column value for [ListIndex](1)]? That is what you should set as the default value.

Comment: The Row Source is"And";"Or";"Not" and I want "And" as the default value.

Comment: Therefore, Default Value `"And"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bound column of the combo is what you should set as the default value. The image below illustrates a Value List, but it would be the same with a Table / Query. If the bound column was 1, and the value shown And (that is, a two-column list), the default value would be set to 1.

[image: default]

Comment: I had tried that and it wasn't working. I closed and re-opened access and it works. Go figure.

Comment: If you are developing, you need to back-up, compact & repair, and decompile fairly often.